# Using Selenium Python to click svg element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium for the first time and while I've found it pretty intuitive I am getting an error message clicking on an svg element.

Here is the portion of the HTML that contains the SVG I want to click:

```
<button class="styles__draftBoardButton__CMJtc">
  <i class="styles__icon__DijND styles__draftBoardIcon__LTcHO">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M25 2.5H5.00003C3.62503 2.5 2.50003 3.625 2.50003 5V25C2.50003 26.375 3.62503 27.5 5.00003 27.5H25C26.375 27.5 27.5 26.375 27.5 25V5C27.5 3.625 26.375 2.5 25 2.5ZM10 25H5.00003V20H10V25ZM10 17.5H5.00003V12.5H10V17.5ZM10 10H5.00003V5H10V10ZM17.5 25H12.5V20H17.5V25ZM17.5 17.5H12.5V12.5H17.5V17.5ZM17.5 10H12.5V5H17.5V10ZM25 25H20V20H25V25ZM25 17.5H20V12.5H25V17.5ZM25 10H20V5H25V10Z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </i>
</button>
```

Here is the portion of code I am using after reading many stack overflow posts:

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/button[1]/i/*[local-name()="svg"]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

I get the following error message:
`ElementNotInteractableException: Message:`

One other piece of information: my code references the Safari web driver (as opposed to Chrome, etc.)

Can you please help me solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code?

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[local-name()="svg"]//path')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//path').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried your code and received the following error message: `TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: I used the full xpath to try to isolate the issue as there are many svg elements on the page.

Comment: As I can see in the above Html code, the SVG element is under the button so you can try below XPath.
//button[@class= 'styles__draftBoardButton__CMJtc']//*[local-name()="svg"]//path')

Comment: do you want to click on the button? or SVG elements within the button?

Comment: Thanks, I tried your proposed xpath but I still receive `TimeoutException: Message: `. When I try your additional suggestion of just the button xpath `//button[@class= "styles__draftBoardButton__CMJtc"]`, I get a different error message: `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: `.